# Is it legit to assume this?

Tags: calculus

I have the following sequence:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-3)^{5n}-2(-3)^n+2}{(-3)^{3n}+(-3)^n+2}$$

I had to find the limit.
So I said that we can just look at the highest power of both the nominator and the denominator so its just like:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-3)^{5n}}{(-3)^{3n}}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(-3)^{2n}=\infty$$

Now I know I right but is it ok to **prove** the limit like this? is it considered "calculus" to say that we can just look at the strongest power?

Comment: A better way is to multiply by $\dfrac{(-3)^{-5n}}{(-3)^{-5n}}$

Comment: @fvel I don't see how to proceed from there, can you elaborate a bit on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right, but it's better to show explicitly what happens to the different terms. Often you can divide the top and bottom by the largest term in the denominator. So, from

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-3)^{5n}-2(-3)^n+2}{(-3)^{3n}+(-3)^n+2}$$

divide by $(-3)^{3n}$ to get:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-3)^{2n}-2(-3)^{-2n}+2(-3)^{-3n}}{1+(-3)^{-2n}+2(-3)^{-3n}}$$

Now you can see that most of the terms will vanish to $0$, leaving $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-3)^{2n}}{1} = \infty$.